# UIBarButtonItem with SF Symbols displays smaller than SystemItem in the navigation bar of document browser

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

In my view controller that extends `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`, I did this

```swift
        additionalTrailingNavigationBarButtonItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(
                image: UIImage(systemName: "book"),
                style: .plain,
                target: self,
                action: nil
            ),
            UIBarButtonItem(
                barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks,
                target: self,
                action: #selector(onReaderButtonClicked)
            ),
        ]
```

and results in

[image: result1]

But if I do similar things in another view controller that is shown by `UINavigationController`

```swift
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(
                image: UIImage(systemName: "book"),
                style: .plain,
                target: nil,
                action: nil
            ),
            UIBarButtonItem(
                barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks,
                target: nil,
                action: nil
            ),
        ]
```

The two icon have the same size as I expected

[image: result2]

Why is the result in pic 1 happened and how can i deal with it?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a custom button in your navigation bar, add bar button items array in right or left position like this:

```
let customButtonWithImage = UIButton(type: .system) // declare your button
```

now in view did load set image, title and assign array of buttons to your navigation bar:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "book")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    
customButtonWithImage.setImage(image, for: .normal)
customButtonWithImage.setTitle(" Select", for: .normal)
customButtonWithImage.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
customButtonWithImage.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal) // set text color
let customNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButtonWithImage)
let navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "book"), style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [customNavBarButton, navBarButton]
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white // set tint color
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue, but be aware you're allowed to specify an `UIImage.SymbolConfiguration` object to be used, when creating an `UIImage` with the `systemName:` method.

The `scale` used on navigation items is `.large`. So if you create the image like this:

```swift
    let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "book", withConfiguration: config)
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ItemsTableViewController.settingsTapped))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

It will create an image that matches the size of a `UIBarButtonItem` created using `barButtonSystemItem:`.

Answer (score 0):

to build on leolobato's answer, here's a custom initializer on UIBarButtonItem that ensures that the image scale is what you want:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(systemImageName: String,
                     scale: UIImage.SymbolScale = .large,
                     target: NSObject? = nil,
                     action: ObjectiveC.Selector? = nil) {
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: scale)
        let image = UIImage(systemName: systemImageName, withConfiguration: config)
        self.init(image: image, style: .plain, target: target, action: action)
    }
}
```